# How to add the second caption by bicaption in a extra lIstoffigures

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, floats, captions, bicaption

I have problems that my second figure caption in English is not showing up the List of Figures by using the package bicaption.
It pops up under the the other entry in the same listoffigure (German one)

```
`\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, headings=normal, twoside]{article} 
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%scrartcl
 \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{bicaption}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Figure}
\usepackage{mwe}`

% Use the bicaption package with list type "figureEng" for the 2nd languagecaptionsetup[bi-second]{listtype+=Eng}
% Define type "figureEng" and listoffigureEng
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof2]{figureEng}[Figure][List of Figures]`

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoffigureEng

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Untersuchungsgebiet}
\label{fig:Untersuchungsgebiet}
\bicaption{Untersuchungsgebiet}{Study area}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an MWE. It would, though, have been even better if it compiled without errors (you have various stray ` characters in it). Also we do not have access to your graphic file; you use the `mwe` package so use one of the images from that. Have you looked at the `ccaption` package for bilingual captions (and lists of)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

**UPDATE** after follow up question

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, headings=normal, twoside]{article} 

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%scrartcl
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[lang=english,listtype+=Eng]{bicaption} % changed <<<<<<<<<<
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Figure}
\captionsetup[table][bi-second]{name=Table}

\usepackage{newfloat}
% Define type "figureEng" and \listoffigureEng
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof2]{figureEng}[Figure][List of Figures]
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lot2]{tableEng}[Table][List of Tables]

\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listoffigureEng
    \listoftableEng

    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:Untersuchungsgebiet}
    \bicaption{Untersuchungsgebiet}{Study area}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        Row 1 Col 1
    \end{tabular}   
    \bicaption{Kleine Tabelle}{Small table}\label{tab:ErsterT}  
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes thats working! Thank you so much

Comment: What do I have to change to get this also for the list of tables?

Comment: @neo94 Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! so cool! Thanks again.